# SQL Server's ISNUMERIC function, with just a minus-sign

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure if this is a question or a warning to other SQL Server users.

We use SQL Server's `ISNUMERIC` function, to determine if a string is a number or not.  But today, we had an issue where the user had passed just a minus sign as their string.

SQL Server's `ISNUMERIC` returns 1 for this string, suggesting that it is a number. 
It *can* `CAST` this string into an int (it casts to a value of 0), but fails when casting it into a numeric.

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(200)

SET @str = '-'

--  This returns 1  (i.e. this string IS a number)
SELECT ISNUMERIC(@str)

--  This works (and returns 0)
SELECT CAST(@str as int)                

--  This throws an error of "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."
SELECT CAST(@str as numeric(12, 0))     

--  This throws an error of "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."
SELECT CAST(@str as numeric(12, 7))
```

Are there any other odd cases where this is likely to happen ?

Comment: My general feeling: Replace `-` with `-1` before the data comes into SQL Server.  This is business logic and would probably be better served in your application layer.

Comment: select isnumeric('3.141e-09') -- for example!  Try and develop a regular expression you can use with LIKE to exactly meet your needs - ISNUMERIC is somewhat flawed and sloppy (although my example is a valid number)

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` answers the question nobody has ever wanted to ask - "can this string by converted to *any* of the numeric data types (I don't care which one(s))?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simple check:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 as num
UNION ALL
SELECT num+1
FROM cte
WHERE num< 256
)

SELECT  num,
        CHAR(num),
        ISNUMERIC(CHAR(num))
FROM cte
WHERE ISNUMERIC(CHAR(num)) = 1 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

This will show that not only *numbers* are considered valid numeric type:

```
$
+
,
-
.
\
€
¤
```

One of the workarounds is to use `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

F.e. if I add this `nd CHAR(num) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to WHERE statement of below query it will return numbers from 0 to 9

Or use `TRY_PARSE(.. as int)`

Some links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: That second (SqlServerCentral) link was what I was looking for.  A bizarre list of single-characters which ISNUMERIC will happily report as being numeric... when they're not.   Okay, lesson learned... I shouldn't rely on using ISNUMERIC before CASTing to a numeric.   Thank you !

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

here's a possible replacement user function - only accepts integers - it cannot guarantee conversion due to maximum integer size limits (which of course vary for BIGINT) - it does accept -1 but rejects -.

```
    -- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Scalar Function (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION ISINTEGER
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @SINT nvarchar(20)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    IF LEN(@SINT) = 0 
        RETURN 0;

    IF LEFT(@SINT, 1) IN('+', '-') AND LEN(@SINT) > 1
        RETURN CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@SINT, 2, 1) IN ('+', '-') THEN 
                                        0 
                                    ELSE   
                                        DBO.ISINTEGER(RIGHT(@SINT, LEN(@SINT) - 1)) 
                                    END;        

    RETURN CASE WHEN @SINT NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

END
GO
```